# Module over a simple ring.

Tags: modules, semi-simple-rings

Let $A$ be a simple ring. Is any $A-$module semi-simple? Why/Why not? (For simplicity, assume that the module is of finite length over $A$.)

EDIT: *When* is an A-module semi-simple and how?

Comment: What about infinite products of $A$?

Comment: Assume that the module is finite dimensional over $A$.

Comment: @J.G. "dimension" is not defined for general rings.

Answer (score 0):

FFR: "Any" is an ambiguous quantifier and is generally avoided in these statements.

If you mean "Is every $A$-module semisimple?" the answer is **no**: it is necessary for $A$ to be additionally *Artinian* for this property to hold for every module.

If you mean "Does there exist a simple $A$ module?" the answer is **yes** because all rings (with identity) have simple modules.

---

> The first line of this proof states that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are each just a sum of (different number of) copies of the unique simple $R$−module $M$. How?

Let $S$ be a simple right ideal. Then the sum of all right ideals isomorphic to $S$ is an ideal, hence all of $R$. Thus $R$ is a semisimple module, and all right ideals are sums of copies of $S$ too. In particular if you have a module homomorphism $R/M\cong S'$ where $S'$ is simple, then by decomposing $R=M\oplus T$ you get that $T$ is just a copy of $S$, and $S\cong S'$. This proves every simple $R$ module is isomorphic to $S$.

You can further look up why the modules of simple Artinian rings decompose into simple modules, and then you will have that every module is a sum of copies of the one type of simple submodule.

Comment: Okay, so say $A$ is Artinian as well. Could you provide a proof as to why the property now holds?

Comment: @J.G. The proof is in almost every noncommutative ring text ever written (e.g. [here, chapters 13+14](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isaacs+graduate+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIgsbug7DPAhVJVT4KHQRCCcwQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Artinian%20ring&f=false), and all over the web (e.g. [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/anderson/rings/LECTURE7.PDF), and I don't intend to regurgitate another proof here...

Comment: I need it to understand the following:

Say $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two finite dimensional modules over a simple $k-$algebra $R$. (The dimension is taken over $k$.) Then the two are isomorphic.

The first line of this proof states that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are each just a sum of (different number of) copies of the unique simple $R-$module M. How?

Comment: @J.G. I added a little bit to show you why there's only one type of simple module for a simple artinian ring.